# Testclass for @future (callout=true)

Tags: apex

New to coding.  I was given this code and am stuck on creating a test class.

```
global class RequestSender_Class {
@future (callout=true)
Public static void sendHTTPRequest(String url, String body){

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setBody(body);
    req.setMethod('POST');

    try {
        res = http.send(req);
    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
        System.debug('CalloutException: '+ e);
        System.debug(res.toString());
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test class, you can enclose the code that calls the future class inside of `test.startTest` and `test.stoptest` and it will automatically call the future class, like this:

```
Test.startTest();
RequestSender_Class.sendHTTPRequest('url string', 'body string');
Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: That's correct, but there needs to be a mock class for the callout as well.

Comment: If you need to know how to mock the callout, the two links on this documentation page will be useful: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing.htm

Comment: @MarkPond Followed the guide but received this error: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATES_DETECTED, You're creating a duplicate record. We recommend you use an existing record instead.: []    Linking to "        res = http.send(req);" line in code above.